# kernel crash by dereference a null pointer

Tags: pointers, linux-kernel, crash

I'm trying something interesting in kernel 2.4.26.
On around line 2367 of `mm/filemap.c`, there is a statement going like this:
`struct inode * inode = file->f_dentry->d_inode;`
I have already verified that I have made `f_dentry` be `NULL` by adding a `printk` right before this statement. Since here `struct inode * inode = file->f_dentry->d_inode;` dereferences a null pointer, the kernel will crash, right? But my computer still works well. I totally have no idea.
Here is the code I have modified (just add a `printk`):

```
if(file->f_dentry == NULL) {
  printk("file->f_dentry is null\n");
}
struct inode * inode = file->f_dentry->d_inode;
```

Here is the information from `dmesg`
[image]

I expect that the kernel will totally crash in dereferencing a null pointer, but it doesn't.

Comment: Please, post resulted code(how and where exactly you call `printk`). You cannot *directly* insert `printk` statement before *definition* of local variable `inode` as C89 standard, used in the kernel, forbid placing anything before definition(except another definition).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your your reply. I have edited my post.Is there a mechanism to protect the kernel from crashing when dereferencing a null pointer in the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect operation in the kernel code doesn't *always* leads to kernel hang (that is, whole machine becomes irresponsible). Sometimes error crash only current thread, like in your case.

Such "partial crash" doesn't mean that error kernel is recovered after the error. After *any* single error no one can garantee that other kernel parts work correct.

Main reason for not hanging *entire kernel* on error is allowing user to store unsaved data and collect information, described the error. Again, no one can garantee that user is able to perform these actions after the particular error, but usually he is.

If you want to *check* whether kernel is correctly works at some moment(no error has been occured until that moment), you can `grep` dmesg output for word "BUG".

Comment: Many thanks for your time. I think this answer partially fixes my problem. But it remains in the other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33234166/kernel-crash-when-dereferencing-a-null-pointer), I have emulated this simple problem. But I don't see why.